# How to extract xml with Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I want to extract  and  from xml with Jquery

I tried this method but it is nothing happend.. :/ I think i have some error in this line `$(xml).find("channel").each(function() {`

```
$(xml).find("channel").each(function() {
  var title = $(this).find("title").text();
  var desc = $(this).find("description").text();
});
```

Here is the xml that i want to extract [XML](http://pastebin.com/Gm5DvD7k)

Is there some other way to do that with JQuery?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that includes some of the XML?

Comment: Just a basic run through shows that your code is OK - maybe it is your XML? http://jsfiddle.net/wBk8c/

Comment: Thank you. I will chack it one more time...